TipKit Parameters incompatible with Swift 6 Concurrency. Property is not concurrency-safe because it is non-isolated global shared mutable state
I'm trying to convert my project to use Swift 6 with Complete Concurrency in Xcode 16 beta 1.
The project uses TipKit, but I'm getting compile errors when trying to use the TipKit Parameters feature. Here is an example of the type of error I'm seeing (Note that this code is copied from: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/tipkit/highlightingappfeatureswithtipkit):
struct ParameterRuleTip: Tip {
    // Define the app state you want to track.
    @Parameter
    static var isLoggedIn: Bool = false

    var rules: [Rule] {
        [
            #Rule(Self.$isLoggedIn) {
                $0 == true
            }
        ]
    }

    ...


Static property '$isLoggedIn' is not concurrency-safe because it is
non-isolated global shared mutable state.

Is there a new pattern for supporting TipKit Parameters in Swift 6 with Complete Concurrency enabled? There is no obvious Xcode suggestion for how to fix this.
The latest WWDC 2024 TipKit doesn't appear to have any solution(s).
Submitted feedback report to Apple (FB13946094).
Any guidance appreciated.
UPDATE July 21, 2024
Fixed in Xcode 16.0 beta 3 (16A5202i)
Related: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/757291

Your question has very little to do with TipKit.
static var isLoggedIn: Bool = false
declares a global variable that is mutable from any code in your module at any time.  That is to say code running in any isolation context.  So it's a mutable variable shared between contexts.
You can either make it so the variable is not shared, or you can make it so it is not mutable. Just from what you've given us it looks like a reasonable declaration might be:
struct ParameterRuleTip: Tip {
    // Define the app state you want to track.
    @Parameter
    static private (set) var isLoggedIn: Bool = false

And you will have to change isLoggedIn with a method inside of the scope of the struct.

I might not be too quick to conclude that this “has very little to do with TipKit”. The problem is the pattern used in Apple’s example (and as illustrated in the 2023 WWDC video) is predicated on the mutable static. Making it immutable or private(set) is not an option. And the issue is that the use of TipKit’s @Parameter macro thwarts the typical solution for mutable global states, i.e., actor isolate it or add your own synchronization.

FWIW, I submitted a feedback report to Apple (FB13945855) and will see what they have to say…

I believe it has to do with how macros are compiled outside of the main target of a project. Hopefully Apple will resolve this in Beta 2.
